# Prove or disprove: if $\sum\limits^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}na_n=0.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question comes from the following problem:

If$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)=S,$ then$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n}{n}=0.$

I want to use Stolz theorem. Thus, I obtain $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n}{n}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}.$$

If we can prove $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}na_n=0,$ the problem is solved. But I wonder whether it holds or not.

Comment: At least we can show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} na_n$ must be $0$ if it exists. (But as the examples in the answers show, it might not exist.)

Comment: This exercise is about Cesaro summability. You can search several literature about this. Try differently, avoid Stolz-Cesaro theorem.

Answer (score 6):

Try the alternating harmonic series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}.$$
If you assume $a_n$ is monotone, then it is true (and is a fun exercise to prove).

Answer (score 4):

Set

$$a_n=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lc}
\frac{1}{k^2} &\mbox{ if } n= k^2 \\
0 & \mbox{ otherwise }
\end{array}
\right.$$

OR
$$b_n=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lc}
\frac{1}{n} &\mbox{ if } n= k^2 \\
\frac{1}{n^2} & \mbox{ otherwise }
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: I feel like this is cheating. Perhaps we should require all $a_n$ be nonzero.

Comment: @eloiPrime see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

By using the literature, as suggested by user @i707107, it is possible to find proofs that there are many successions of coefficients $\langle a_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=L<\infty\text{ does not imply }\lim_{n \to \infty} na_n=0\iff a_n=o(n)
$$
Precisely, the basic theorem on alternating series (see for example [1], pp. 156-157) states that every series of the form
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nb_n,
$$
where $b_n\ge 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a strictly monotonically decreasing sequence, converges, no matter how slow is the vanishing rate of the coefficients, and also 
$$
R_m=\left|\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} a_n\right|=\left|\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty (-1)^nb_n\right|<b_{m+1}=|a_{m+1}| \quad \forall m\in\mathbb{N}
$$
Therefore, **any arbitrarily chosen strictly and slowly monotonically decreasing succession of positive numbers can be used to construct a counterexample to the main assertion of the question**: for example the succession $a_n=(-1)^n \big[\log(\log(n+1))\big]^{-1}$ satisfies the requirements.

However, the sought for result, i.e.
$$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)=s \text{ implies }\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n}{n}=0.
$$

is true: you can look at the proofs of Tauber's second theorem, for example the one offered by Jan Van de Lune [2], §1.2 p. 4, to see how to proceed.

[1] Emanuel Fisher (1983), "*Intermediate Real Analysis*", Springer Verlag

[2] Jan van de Lune, (1986), "*[An introduction to Tauberian theory: from Tauber to Wiener](http://persistent-identifier.org/?identifier=urn:nbn:nl:ui:18-12912)*", CWI Syllabus, 12, Amsterdam: CWI, pp. iv+102, ISBN 90-6196-309-5, MR 0882005, Zbl 0636.40002